# How do I force IE10 to use https (without an add-on)?

Tags: browser, https, internet-explorer-10

I would like to force IE10 to autocomplete "https://" instead of "http://" when I enter a URL. I'm limited in that I can't use 3rd party plugins (on a corporate computer where it's locked down).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can't.  Even Firefox and Chrome require extensions in order to do this.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I'm newly back to Windows as an OS and figured I'd see if anyone knew of a buried setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is "you can't".

Suppose it should have been obvious to me after thinking I had to add the condition "without plugins" (there wouldn't be a plugin if it were natively supported). Thanks for the confirmation @Ramhound.